languageserver package not recognized for R extension on Visual Studio Code
I am using the R extension in VS Code to run R on a Windows 10 computer.
I am trying to use radian for interactive sessions following here: https://aeturrell.com/blog/posts/setting-up-r-in-vscode/
My VS Code JSON R settings include the following (in addition to some non-R settings):
    "r.bracketedPaste": true,
    "r.alwaysUseActiveTerminal": true,
    "r.plot.useHttpgd": true,
    "r.rpath.windows": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.4.1\\bin\\x64\\R.exe",
    "r.rterm.windows": "C:\\Users\\XXXX\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python39\\Scripts\\radian.exe"

When I open an R File it prompts me that:
R package {languageserver} is required to enable R language service features such as code completion, function signature, find references, etc. Do you want to install it?

However, I have the languageserver package installed.
Two potential pieces to the puzzle:
I can open an interactive R session "R: create R terminal." I believe this is running the radian .exe because when I hover over the terminal, it shows the radian .exe path.
However, in the VS code powershell, I cannot call R. I get the following return:
try { . "c:\Users\XXXX\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\resources\app\out\vs\workbench\contrib\terminal\browser\media\shellIntegration.ps1" } catch {}

In the VS code powershell, however, I can call radian.
Using the command prompt outside VS code, I can call R and radian. So there seems to be some issue with VS Code recognizing the R path.
I tried to install the languageserver as they suggest, but then the error reappears.
